# Show child div on hover, hide it on mouseout, but remain shown if child div is hovered

Tags: jquery

I have a div that when hovered shows a child div element. When the mouse is not hovering the parent div, the child disappears. How can I make it so that the child doesn't disappear if it the mouse leaves the parent div but hovers straight onto the child element?

```
$('.parentelement li ').hover(function(){

    $(this).find('.childelement').fadeIn();

}, function() {
   $(this).find('.childelement').fadeOut();
});
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: jquery version? and browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
$('.parentelement li ').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('.childelement').fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('.childelement').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: I haven't tested but jquery docs says hover is a short hand for what you got here...

Comment: @Huangism The mouseleave event only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the element it is bound to, not a descendant unlike hover

Comment: right what I meant is what you have here is the same thing as the OP's code except it is not a shorthand http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Indeed, thank you pXL, but .hover() is shortcode for mousenter , mouseleave, so it gives identical results.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RhMj9/1/ this gives the same result on FF with jquery 1.9  the original hover code works with 1.9 so which jquery version of jquery is OP using?

Comment: Ah, I left out some code, It's not a direct parent, and I'm using .parent to find the other div. I updated the jfiddle so you can see it in action http://jsfiddle.net/Txmrx/2/

Comment: do this http://jsfiddle.net/Txmrx/3/  set the hover element to the parent which is outer in this case

Comment: Yes I will have to do that, and adjust the css of the child target to all work properly. Thanks a lot guys :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.parentelement li, .childelement ').hover(function(){
      $(this).find('.childelement').fadeIn();}, 
function() {
      $(this).find('.childelement').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: possibly can cause double fade, need some testing

Comment: if he doesn't specify time to fadein and fadeout, he could use show() and hide() instead, or set visible attribute to true or false

Comment: That is perfect, thank you. One slight issue though is that if you move the mouse slowly to the child element and you hover right when it is fading out, it pauses the fadeout and remains half visible. Is there a way to make it go back to full opacity?

Comment: try this then:
$('.parentelement li, .childelement ').hover(function(){
          $(this).find('.childelement').attr("visibility", "visible"); },
    function() {
          $(this).find('.childelement').attr("visibility", "hidden"); 
    });

Comment: Thanks, but I really need to use the fade in/out.